# Introduction to Topological Manifolds Problem 7-14

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, surfaces

The problem is asking me to prove there exists a point in a compact connected surface that is not homeomorphic to the sphere, such that removing this point will give a space homotopic equivalent to a bouquet of circles. I haven't got any intuition to approach it. Could somebody offer a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the surface is oriented You can draw the fundamental domain, it is a $2g$-gon, if you remove a point inside, the resulting space as a fundamental domain which retract to the boundary of the $2g$-gon, i.e the space retract to a bouquet of $2g$-circles.